# How to use font-awesome classes for toggles instead of unicodes or .svg images

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I would like to use font-awesome classes instead of unicodes or .svg (or any image) to obtain the same toggle effect that I have below. However, I am struggling in finding an example where classes are used in the HTML for toggles. I'd really appreciate your help.

Here's my CodePen if you find it easier: 
https://codepen.io/fergos2/pen/vYYgYzp

The same code is below and please note that font-awesome and jQuery are imported in the CodePen and that I am using SCSS as the CSS preprocessor.

Thanks in advance for helping me!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    $('.toggle').toggleClass('active');
    $('.toggle-content').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```
.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggle {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;

  &:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f085"; // fas fa-cogs
  }
}

.toggle.active {
  background-color: red;

  &:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f00d"; // fas fa-times
  } 
}

.toggle-content {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-content.active{
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="toggle"></div>
    <div class="toggle-content">
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
Solved with my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-1').click(function() {
    if ($('.toggle-2').hasClass('active')) {
      // remove toggle-2 active classes
      $('.toggle-2').removeClass('active');
            $('.toggle-2-content').removeClass('active');
    }

    $(this).find('.toggle-icon').toggleClass('fa-plus-circle fa-times active');
    $('.toggle-1').toggleClass('active');
    $('.toggle-1-content').toggleClass('active');
  });

  $('.toggle-2').click(function() {
    if ($('.toggle-1').hasClass('active')) {
      // remove toggle-1 active classes
      $('.toggle-1').removeClass('active');
            $('.toggle-1-content').removeClass('active');
    }

    $(this).find('.toggle-icon').toggleClass('fa-heart fa-times active');
    $('.toggle-2').toggleClass('active');
    $('.toggle-2-content').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```
.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggle-1,
.toggle-2 {
    display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

.toggle-icon {
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.toggle-1.active,
.toggle-2.active {
  background-color: red;
  content: "\f342";
}

.toggle-1-content,
.toggle-2-content {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-1-content.active,
.toggle-2-content.active {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">


    <div class="toggle-1"><a href="javascript:void"><i class="toggle-icon fas fa-cogs"></i></a></div>
    <div class="toggle-1-content">
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>

        <div class="toggle-2"><a href="javascript:void"><i class="toggle-icon fas fa-heart"></i></a></div>
    <div class="toggle-2-content">
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```